# Estimate jaccard similarity mean

Tags: igraph, similarity

I am working with a network where I am trying to extract the mean value per `vertex`of the `jaccard similarity`. I am calculating this in R by using the igraph package. The similarity index estimates a value betweenn each `two vertices`. The network has `177 vertices`, therefore `177` values. It may be easy, but I have not found out the best way to do it.

Comment: Please create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), otherwise it is very hard for us to help solve your problem.

Comment: OK, no problem: so I have: `SJaccard <- similarity(g, vids = V(g), mode = c("total"),  loops = TRUE, method = c("jaccard"))`, where my network `g` is: `V(g)=177, and E(g)=10547`, it is very dense. The idea is to track vertex similarity. I want to test if the vertex average of `jaccard index` as measure of similarity decays as the network closeness increases.

Comment: `igraph` gives me a list of 177 values per each vertex, I just want to substrack the mean of each. However, given that I am working with a graph object, It is difficult for me to estimate the maean value of the `jaccard_similarity` for each vertex.

Comment: You have not made a reproducible example, yet

Comment: ok, so if we have `g <- make_ring(5)`
`similarity(g, method="jaccard")`, so we obtain a 5x5 matrix:                  `[,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]`
`[1,] 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000`
`[2,] 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333`
`[3,] 0.3333333 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.3333333`
`[4,] 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.0000000`
`[5,] 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000 1.0000000` and then, I need the similarity mean value of each five vertices.

Answer (score 1):

Sum the columns (or rows), subtract 1 (for the vertex similarity with itself), divide by n-1 rows (or columns)

```
library(igraph)
g <- make_ring(5) 
m <-similarity(g, method="jaccard")
(colSums(m)-1)/(nrow(m)-1)

#[1] 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
```

Comment: excelent, thanks it works, I was using .rowMeans but, it was far from the correct answer.